# Timeline with UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, timeline

I'm trying to code a Timeline for my app. I designed it on sketch in order to give you an insight:

[image]

I'm not an expert in Swift so I don't really know how to code it. I've thought about creating a UICollectionView, and play with the indexPath in order to change the design of the cell if it's even or odd.

What do you think ?

Comment: It sounds correct. Either two differents custom UICollectionViewCell, and counting on the odd/even row, or potentially, if you always have a big with photo+time and a smaller with a text, a custom UICollectionViewCell with theses two views.

Comment: UITableView is Best for this type of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how can this design done?

you have two way to implement like this design:

First one (easiest way): 
What you need is just a tableView with timeline view (UICollectionView) at the top with 2 custom collection view cells one for odd and the other for even
tableview will have 2 cells also one for text with image and the other for plane text

how to render time line:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (indexPath.row + 1) % 2 == 0 {
        return even cell
    } else {
        return odd cell
    }
```

how to detect even or odd by calculate indexPath while the user scroll through timeline :

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTimeLine: UICollectionView!
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let timeline = scrollView as? collectionViewTimeLine {
        // calculate and find selected indexPath
        // reload data
    }
}
```

The second way:
This way is used when you want to smoothly animate content while the user scroll through timeline

You need a 2 UICollectionView the first for time line and the second for content
When user scroll timeline you scroll the collectionViewContent

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTimeLine: UICollectionView!
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let timeline = scrollView as? collectionViewTimeLine {
            // calculate and find selected indexPath
            // scroll collectionViewContent with selected indexPath
        }
    }
```